# Add placeholder to BoundedIntText - ipywidgets

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

I am wondering if it is possible to add a placeholder into a `BoundedIntText` `ipywidget`. This is possible in other types such as

```
widgets.Text(
    value='Hello World',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
```

I need to use `BoundedIntText` since the user input must be a number within a range (0 - 175). I would like to print the placeholder to inform users about that range, but as far as I know it is not possible.

```
widgets.BoundedIntText(
    value=7,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    step=1,
    description='Text:',
    disabled=False
)
```

Any suggestion on this?
Thks

Comment: I didn't know about `placeholder` thanks! I guess because the placeholder you want wouldn't be the right type for the widget (you need string, it supports int only) , you can't use it. Perhaps place the max and min in the `description`?

Comment: @ac24 adding it to the description would be indeed a work-around solution, but I am looking for a cleaner layout!